# loading only chosen modules during end to end tests with puppeteer

Tags: express, jestjs, puppeteer

I have the frontend application which has react client and express.js based server. Such configuration is needed.

I would like to write the end-to-end using jest and puppeteer. During tests I would like the application to not load some modules (auth for example).

In my server.js file I have:

```js
import express from 'express';
import oauth2 from './utils/oauth2';

// some code

const app = express();
app.use(oauth2);
```

is there any good practice how to not import and not to use some modules,  like `oauth2` in the example code, if `NODE_ENV === 'e2e'`?

Comment: The environment variable approach should work. What exactly is the question here?

Comment: @Thomas Dondorf can you provide an example?

Comment: I think your idea is fine: `if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'e2e') { app.use(oauth2); }` (alternatively use another environment variable)

Comment: But it still imports it, what throws an error

Comment: Oh, I see. Is this TypeScript or Webpack? You need [dynamic imports](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-4.html#dynamic-import-expressions).

Comment: Nice, looks like solution I was looking for. Thank you!!

Comment: I can also add a more detailed answer. So, you are using Typescript then?

Comment: Anyway, is it a good practice?

Comment: No, I don't use TS

Comment: Yes, there is nothing wrong with only loading the modules you need during runtime. I guess you are using Webpack then? (I can add a more detailed answer later if you want)